# How to configure S3 endpoint to prevent access to buckets outside current region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to prevent access by valid principals in my account to buckets outside of my account, and am trying to use an S3 endpoint.

My account is in `us-east-1` and my buckets are in the same region. When I configure an S3 endpoint and allow access through endpoint policy only to specific buckets, I see that access to other buckets in the same region is denied. While this seems intuitive, there is no explicit deny in either the principal's IAM policy or the bucket policy.

Therefore, **question #1**: is this the expected endpoint behavior?

Now, if I try to access bucket in `us-west-1`, I am able to access it, even though there's no `Allow` clause in endpoint policy and I have no other presence in `us-west-1`. This implies that an endpoint policy only applies to buckets defined in the same region as the endpoint.

Therefore, **question #2**: is my observation correct? If so, how do I prevent access to arbitrary buckets, definitely those outside my account, in regions other than current one (`us-east-1`)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use IAM roles to restrict access to resources in other regions. 
There is a write up on it [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/easier-way-to-control-access-to-aws-regions-using-iam-policies/)

I can't confirm the endpoint behavior but your logic seems sound.